# Production Storybook code shows 'WithStyles' instead of component name for Material-UI

Tags: material-ui, storybook

I am using Storybook to document a design system using [Material-UI (v4)](https://v4.mui.com/) components. When building my Storybook for production:

```bash
$ npm run build-storybook
$ npx http-server storybook-static -o
```

The code blocks display `WithStyles` instead of component names. For example, a code block that should appear as:

```
<Button
  color="default"
  onClick={() => {}}
  size="medium"
  variant="contained"
>
  Hello World
</Button>
```

Instead appears as:

```
<WithStyles
  color="default"
  onClick={function noRefCheck(){}}
  size="medium"
  variant="contained"
>
  Hello World
</WithStyles>
```

I inquired in the Storybook Discord and part of the answer I got was:

> Storybook uses react-element-to-jsx-string to generate the source blocks, and that library relies on element's displayNames. It looks like you're using MUI, which does not assign displayName in production environments.

But the person helping me was unsure how to overcome this.

Is there a workaround to get Storybook to properly generate the code blocks when building Material-UI components in production?